# Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-google-charts/dist/types'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-component, react-google-charts, webpack.config.js

I am working on react application where I have used react google charts for displaying Line chart with annotation. But I am getting an issue with role attribute for column in Line chart, have already imported react-google-charts in the working component. Below is my code:

Home.tsx > component

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Chart } from 'react-google-charts';
import GoogleDataTableColumnRoleType from 'react-google-charts/dist/types';

export class Home extends React.Component<IChildComponentProps,AddDataState> {
    
constructor(props) {
        super(props);

public render() {

 <div id="chart_div2">
     <Chart
            width={400}
            height={'300px'}
            chartType="LineChart"
            loader={<div>Loading Chart</div>}
            rows={this.state.o3TargetChart}
            columns={[
                {
                    type: "string",
                    label: "Week"
                },
                {
                    type: "number",
                    label: "O3Done"
                },
                {
                    type: "string",
                     role: GoogleDataTableColumnRoleType.annotation // getting error here
                   
                },
                {
                    type: "number",
                    label: "Target"
                }
            ]}
            options={{
                title: '',
                hAxis: {
                    title: 'Week', titleTextStyle: {
                    },
                    baselineColor: '#cccccc'
                },
                vAxis: {
                    title: 'O3 Coverage ( in %)', minValue: 0, maxValue: 100, titleTextStyle: {
                    },
                    baselineColor: '#cccccc',
                },
                pointsVisible: true,
                chartArea: {
                    left: 100
                },
                height: 400,
                width: 1000,
            }}
        />

                                    </div>

}

}
```

Although I can find the type module under node_modules directory as below:

node_modules\react-google-charts\dist\types.d.ts

Have already added below code in webpack.config.js file as suggested by others:

```
 resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
```

Still I am getting module not found error. Please suggest..

Comment: did you try console.log `GoogleDataTableColumnRoleType`

Comment: @angelo do u think console.log will work inside render function?

Comment: you can try in componentDidMount